# Proofs for "Every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set"

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, measurable-sets

In attempting to learn about measure theory, I have now come to a problem that I've seen previously on StackExchange.

The exercise is to prove that every interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set.

Here is a notable post on the problem [Show that every interval is a Borel set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296165/show-that-every-interval-is-a-borel-set)

I am wondering what alternate proofs exist besides demonstrating that, given every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set, the intersections $[a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n})$, $(a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a, b+\frac{1}{n})$, and $[a,b) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b)$ capture all intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

Where may I find proofs showing that $\sigma \mathcal{C} = \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ (where $\sigma \mathcal{C}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the collection of all intervals of $\mathbb{R}$) or proving this in other ways that do not immediately come to mind?

I would appreciate any wisdom / insights into the matter.

Comment: Add to that the intervals that diverage to $\pm \infty$ and I think you are finished.

Comment: Alternatively, after observing that singleton sets are Borel sets, once you have $[a,b],$ then you immediately get the half-open intervals by subtracting appropriate singleton sets.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That's intriguing! I had not pondered that idea. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: The various ideas in the answers/comments to [Showing that a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Borel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/943379/13130) might be of interest.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I downloaded the article for When Is a Point Borel. Thank you for bringing that post to my attention.

Comment: Once you prove that singletons sets are Borel sets, then, since you know $(a,b)$ are Borel sets, it follows easily that $[a,b)$, $(a,b]$ and $[a,b]$ are Borel sets.